# How to disable mat-spinner when I receive Job Success/Failure Notification from back-end

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have an asynchronous job which takes a long time to execute.
When the job starts executing I had set a mat-spinner and set the timeout for 60000 milliseconds. 
But now we have a notification service which tells the status of Job Execution.
I want to disable the spinner when a Message is received irrespective of whether a job failed/passed.

Code for a spinner with timeout:-

```
 this.recommendationService
                    .executeCustomerOpportunityMapper(opportuniyMapperJson)
                    .subscribe(
                        response => {
                            this.isExecuteOppRanking = true;
                            this.snakbar.statusBar(
                                "Executing customer opportunity ranking",
                                "Success"
                            );
                            this.spinner.show();
                            setTimeout(() => {
                                this.spinner.hide();

this.loadRankedOpportunities(tableMetadata);
                                this.selectedIndex = 3;
                                this.isExecuteOppRanking = false;
                            }, 60000);
```

Message Notification Service:-

```
this.messageService.messageReceived$.subscribe(data => {
        this.snakbar.statusBar("Platform job status - " + data, "Info");

    });
```

I want my spinner to timeout when messageService receives a success/failure notification rather than timing out after 60000 ms.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that both of your subscriptions are located in the same component, if  you want to stop the spinner, can you move `spinner.hide()` to the other subscription?

```
this.messageService.messageReceived$.subscribe(data => {
    this.snakbar.statusBar("Platform job status - " + data, "Info");
    if (data === "done") { // somehow check the status if necessary
        this.spinner.hide();
        this.loadRankedOpportunities(tableMetadata);
        this.selectedIndex = 3;
        this.isExecuteOppRanking = false;
    }
});

this.recommendationService
    .executeCustomerOpportunityMapper(opportuniyMapperJson)
    .subscribe(response => {
        this.isExecuteOppRanking = true;
        this.snakbar.statusBar(
            "Executing customer opportunity ranking",
            "Success"
        );
        this.spinner.show();
     });
```

Comment: It doesn't work ...its throwing error.Metadata is not defined outside the scope of executeCustomerOpportunity so when i call it in ngOninit its throwing error